# Polymer 2 - display one element when click on another

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, polymer-2.x, custom-element

I have used Polymer 2 to create two custom elements:

- a button
- a overlay element

i am importing and using them both on another "main element".

What i would like to do is to toggle a class on the "overlay element" with each "button" click.

Is it possible to do this? Can i share data-bindings between elements?

Answer (score 2):

Using the adage "events up, props down," sibling elements share data through their parent. There are various solutions for this. I'm using [Redux](https://github.com/tur-nr/polymer-redux) to share data across several elements, but simple parent-to-*n*-children approach works:

In main-element.html

```
<button-element id="button"></button-element>
<overlay-element id="overlay"></overlay-element>
...
ready() {
  super.ready();
  this.$.button.addEventListener('toggle', this._onUpdate);
}
_onUpdate(event) {
  this.$.overlay.toggle = !this.$.overlay.toggle;
}
```

In button-element.html

```
<button on-click="_doClick">Ok</button>
...
_doClick(event) {
  this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('toggle'));
}
```

In overlay-element.html

```
<div>[[status]]</div>
...
static get properties() {
  return {
    toggle: {
      type: Boolean,
      observer: '_toggleChanged'
    },
    status: {
      type: String
    }
...
_toggleChanged(newValue, oldValue) {
  this.status = newValue ? 'I\'m hit.' : 'Missed me.';
}
```

See [this pen](https://codepen.io/johnthad/pen/zRXpOB?editors=1001).